# arm timer interrupt (arm_arch_timer)

Tags: linux-kernel, arm

I am tracing some SMP timer code on Linux. I found out that some platform using the ARM arch_arm_timer which is arm core internal timer.

The device tree definition is as follows:

```
    timer {
            compatible = "arm,armv7-timer";
            interrupts = <1 13 0xf08>,
                         <1 14 0xf08>,
                         <1 11 0xf08>,
                         <1 10 0xf08>;
    };
```

I am confused. Why are its interrupt numbers 13 14 11 10? I check the GIC manual and its private timer using ID 29.

Comment: You should always look in 'Documentation/devicetree/bindings' for documentation in what the DT means.

Comment: got it thanks!
The 1st cell is the interrupt type; 0 for SPI interrupts, 1 for PPI
  interrupts.

  The 2nd cell contains the interrupt number for the interrupt type.
  SPI interrupts are in the range [0-987].  PPI interrupts are in the
  range [0-15].

Answer (score 1):

So, and this is a guess, I think these refer to Private Peripheral Interrupt IDs. The generic timer is wired up in [the Cortex-A15](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0438i/BGBDJJJD.html) to interrupts 26, 27, 29, 30. Since the PPIs range from ID 16 to ID 31, these refer to

- Secure Physical Timer event (ID 29 <= 16 + 13)
- Non-secure Physical Timer event (ID 30 <= 16 + 14)
- Virtual Timer event    (ID 27 <= 16 + 11)
- Hypervisor Timer event (ID 26 <= 16 + 10)

Comment: Indeed, the interrupt format is documented in [the GIC bindings](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/arm/gic.txt?id=refs/tags/v3.16-rc4), and [the Generic Timer bindings](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/arm/arch_timer.txt?id=refs/tags/v3.16-rc4) specify the ordering.